# rerouting name to ip on local network

Tags: ip, domain-name, hosts

i created an intranet (lamp) and now i have to make it visible using this url 
**intranet**:

the solution i found was to put in each computers (mac, windows) this in the hosts file using the ip 192.168.1.100 and the alias intranet

the intranet has a static ip

i dont want to change all of themsince i have 50+ computers. is there an easy way to make all the computers use http//intranet instead of http//192.168.1.100

Comment: serverfault.com does not allow DNS questions?

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly why DNS was invented. Set up a DNS server. If you already have one, make use of it.

Comment: any idea how? I am using ubuntu

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO.html